# Android app crashing - unknown reason

Tags: android, crash

I am a beginner and have been using treehouse to learn. I am very early in the course and suddenly started getting a crash message when I start the app. I am unsure what is happening. I have posted everything that I know of. Sorry if I missed something or posted too much.

Main:

```
package com.example.crystalball;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private CrystalBall mCrystalBall = new CrystalBall();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Declare our View variables
    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String answer = mCrystalBall.getAnAnswer();

            // Update label with dynamic answer
            answerLabel.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

CrystalBall:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.crystalball"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crystalball.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.crystalball"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crystalball.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
07-28 01:50:31.530: D/AndroidRuntime(980): Shutting down VM
07-28 01:50:31.530: W/dalvikvm(980): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ae7ba8)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980): Process: com.example.crystalball, PID: 980
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crystalball/com.example.crystalball.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.example.crystalball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-28 01:50:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  ... 11 more
07-28 01:50:37.070: I/Process(980): Sending signal. PID: 980 SIG: 9
```

Comment: change  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: " `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Activity extends `ActionBarActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Indicates you are using `AppCompat` in which case you need to set `Theme` derieved from `Theme.AppCompat` to the Activity

or

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

set the theme for the application

Answer (score 0):

To simply add ActionBar Compat your activity or application should use `@style/Theme.AppCompat` theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
   <activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```

This will add actionbar in activty(or all activities if you added this theme to application)

i.e. in your manifest file,Change

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat"
```